# Convert any number range to -1/1 scale

Tags: c#, math

I need to convert any range to a -1 to 1 scale.  I have multiple ranges that I am using and therefore need this equation to be dynamic.  Below is my current equation.  It works great for ranges where 0 is the centerpoint. I.E. 200 to -200.  I have another range however that isn't converting nicely.  6000 to 4000.  I've also tested 0 to 360 and it works.

```
var offset = -1 + ((2 / yMax) * (point.Y));
```

One of the major issues that I may have is that sometimes I'll get a value that is outside the range, and as such, the converted value needs to also be outside the -1 to 1 range.

What this is for is to take a value that is a real world value, and I need to be able to plot it into an OpenGL point.  I'm using .NET 4.0 and the Tao Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rescaled = -1 + 2 * (point.Y - yMin) / (yMax - yMin);
```

However, in OpenGL you can do this with a projection matrix (or matrix multiply inside a shader).  Read about `glTranslatef` and `glScalef` for how to use them or how to duplicate them with matrix multiply.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks.  I debated using matrix multiply, but the issue I had was only the Y coordinate needed scaled.  The X coordinate was already in range.  I'll accept this answer as soon as it lets me.